# Windows Server: Adding an additional Host entry for a domain computer?

Tags: domain-name-system, windows

For a couple of reasons (I'll explain later), I'm looking to add an additional A record for a system in my domain in the Windows Server 2012 DNS Manager. It sticks for a few minutes... but then gets automatically deleted (I assume by Active Directory). How can I add that additional A record and have it stick? Or is there a better way to accomplish this?

I'm looking to get something like this nslookup response for a system that only has a single network adapter:

```
Name:   system.domain.local
Address: 1.2.3.4
Name:   system.domain.local
Address: 5.6.7.8
```

Apologies if this question's been asked already, but I haven't found an answer for it while searching. :(

**Explanation**: I'm not trying to have a fully redundant domain setup. As such, I have my domain controller behind a NAT, so it believes its primary IP is an internal IP. I would like to connect a single Linux system outside the NAT to the domain, though, and Centrify's satisfied if I can get the system to resolve with both the internal and external IP. In an attempt to minimize my exposure, I've only opened up the ports that Centrify insists on, and I have it locked down to only accept connections from the one external host.

Comment: As noted in a below comment, I've already done the obvious of adding an A host entry in DNS Manager. That's what's being automatically deleted. In addition, scavenging is turned off on the record as well as the domain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Recording this in the unlikely chance that anybody else encounters this:

From what I can tell (after turning on auditing of the DNS manager), the target client is updating its own entry in the DNS. This is the primary zone, so "Dynamic updates" was set to "Secure only", but that's enough for the client to replace its own entry. Since both IPs were being stored in a single object (according to ADSI Edit), the other A record was getting blown away.

It looks like the easiest way to get around this is to create another Forward Lookup Zone, `system.domain.local` with  "Dynamic updates" set to "None", and create the A record *there*, so that the entry won't get clobbered.

Answer (score 0):

1. Open DNS snap-in by opening Run (Windows key + r) on the DNS server (probably your Domain Controller server) and type in `dnsmgmt.msc`.
2. Click the correct domain and then right click it, select New, select A record.
3. Fill the required fields and click 'save'.
4. Check it.

Comment: That's what I've already done. That's the record that gets wiped out, so this just covers the obvious. Except the obvious doesn't work, which is why I'm asking.